# Pandas Long to Wide conversion

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas. I have a data set with in this format.

```
     UserID         ISBN    BookRatings
0   276725.0    034545104U      0.0
1   276726.0    155061224       5.0
2   276727.0    446520802       0.0
3   276729.0    052165615W      3.0
4   276729.0    521795028       6.0
```

I would like to create this

```
        ISBN    276725  276726  276727  276729
       UserID               
0    034545104U         
1        0     155061224    0        0       0
2        0         0    446520802    0       0
3        0         0        0    052165615W  0
4        0         0        0     521795028  0
```

I tried pivot but was not successful. Any kind advice please?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71455582/edit).

Comment: Why did you edit your answer and replaced the tables with images? Images of tables are not helpful. Nobody wants to type in all values on an image :P

Comment: ok noted. After posting the formatted text look strange so I thought an image is better.

Comment: No worries. I adapted my answer to your data now. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `pivot()` is the right approach here. The most difficult part is to get the arguments correctly. I think we need to keep the original index and the new columns should be the values in column `UserID`. Also, we want to fill the new dataframe with the values from column `ISBN`.

For this, I firstly extract the original index as column and then apply the `pivot()` function:

```
df = df.reset_index()
result = df.pivot(index='index', columns='UserID', values='ISBN')
# Make your float columns to integers (only works if all user ids are numbers, drop nan values first)
result.columns = map(int,result.columns)
```

Output:

```
           276725     276726     276727      276729
index                                              
0      034545104U        NaN        NaN         NaN
1             NaN  155061224        NaN         NaN
2             NaN        NaN  446520802         NaN
3             NaN        NaN        NaN  052165615W
4             NaN        NaN        NaN   521795028
```

**Edit:** If you want the same appearance as in the original dataframe you have to apply the following line as well:

```
result = result.rename_axis(None, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
       276725     276726     276727      276729
0  034545104U        NaN        NaN         NaN
1         NaN  155061224        NaN         NaN
2         NaN        NaN  446520802         NaN
3         NaN        NaN        NaN  052165615W
4         NaN        NaN        NaN   521795028
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem I had as you rightly mentioned is that it only works with numbers. Strings gives errors.

Comment: If you do not need the entries that have strings as `userid`. You can filter them out with `df = df[~df['UserID'].isnull()]`. Otherwise, you have to give me some example and tell me how strings should be processed.

Comment: You're welcome! Is the question already answered or do you have any other issues?